# Unable to write more than 4 characters in memory allocated in process 0 from other processes

Tags: mpi

I am a little confused about this code. The first thing is I have read many posts that advise not to send a pointer in MPI. But I am sending one here and it is working. Another problem I have with this code is that it can write maximum 4 characters from other processes to process 0's allocated memory as in code. Can somebody explain a little ?

```c
#include<mpi.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int MyRank, NumProcs, index, ret;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_File cFile;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&MyRank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&NumProcs);
    //Allocated memory for a double pointer.
    char **var;
    MPI_Alloc_mem(sizeof(char *)*NumProcs, MPI_INFO_NULL, &var);
    for(index = 0; index < NumProcs; index++)
        MPI_Alloc_mem(sizeof(char)*50, MPI_INFO_NULL, &var[index]);
    if(MyRank == 0)
    { 
        //Copied data to the 0th position of the double pointer
        strcpy(var[MyRank],"KKKKKK");
        //Process 0 sent the array to other process to overwrite the data
        for(index = 1; index < NumProcs; index++)
            MPI_Send(var[index],1,MPI_INT,index,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD );
        for(index = 1; index < NumProcs; index++)
            MPI_Recv(var[index],1,MPI_INT,index,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    }
    else
    {
        //Overwrite of data is done. 
        MPI_Recv(var[MyRank],1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        strcpy(var[MyRank],"MMMMMM");
        MPI_Send(var[MyRank],1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    }
    if(MyRank == 0)
    {
        //After writing data, printed in process 0;
        printf("My Rank is -%d\n", MyRank);
        for(index = 0; index < NumProcs; index++)
            printf(" %s\n",var[index]);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you allocate all `NumProcs` strings in a continuous block of memory, you can use `MPI_Scatter` and `MPI_Gather` instead of looping over all ranks with `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv`. Also use `malloc` for simple allocation cases instead of `MPI_Alloc_mem`. The latter is mainly intended for allocating _special_ memory (whatever _special_ means in the context of the specific MPI implementations).

Answer (score 3):

When you say `MPI_Send(var[index],1,MPI_INT,index,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD );` you tell the compiler to send 1 integer. On a 32-bit system, this is only 4 bytes.

You probably want to alter all of your send and receive lines to have the same parameters as `MPI_Send(var[index],50,MPI_CHAR,index,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD );`

Just to clear up your misunderstanding about sending a pointer: MPI doesn't actually "send a pointer". The code above will start at the `char` pointed to by `var[index]` and send that `char` and the next 49 `chars`.